# Beginner Java Error

Tags: java

I understand the philosophy of use of the website is to ask complex/original questions yet as a beginner I cannot grasp where my code is incorrect and would love some help.

The objective of the code below is to merely sum an array of integers, yet eclipse keeps telling me to insert ; I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Many thanks in advance.

```
class SumArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int [] x ={1,2,3,4};
    Sum(x);
    }


public static void Sum(int [] a) {
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        counter+=a[i];
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Eclipse will tell you that at a specific place.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

 at SumArray.main(HelloWorld.java:4)

Comment: I don't think you saved after you made edits. There's no missing semicolon here.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/IaDaNN

Comment: Does this mean that my code is correct but i am using eclipse in an incorrect fashion? I just resaved my code and ran it again and recieved the same errors *sadface*

Comment: @BobDole See the problem below.

Comment: Is there anything else in your HelloWorld.java file?

Comment: The problem was a combination of what malik brahimi and champfish posted, thanks for all the help everyone, many thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you named your file HelloWorld but your class SumArray, change to:

```
public class HelloWorld
```

Comment: i think you might to correct, let me see

Comment: thanks friend, you were correct along with champfish

Comment: You are also missing a brace at the very end of your class.

Comment: done, but how do i give credit to champfish also?

Comment: I can upvote him for you. I think the brace is secondary to the class name, and I did after all answer first.

Answer (score 1):

One error is that the Sum method doesn't have a end }. Not sure if that solves your problem though.

```
    class SumArray {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        int [] x ={1,2,3,4};
        Sum(x);
        }


    public static void Sum(int [] a) {
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            counter+=a[i];
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    } //missing this
}
```

Comment: Also as Malik Brahimi said your class should be named the same as your file name.

Comment: many thanks friend, this was the error along with what @Malik Brahimi Mentioned

Comment: I think a brace is a minor error when compared to the class name. Eclipse can easily identify missing braces when given the right class name.

Answer (score 0):

Your SumArray class doesn't have an ending bracket. Try adding a "}" to the end of your code.

Comment: Look at the error in the comments? What is the name of his file and what is the name of his class?